# Cocoa touch static libraries can be use in Mac OSX too?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa-touch, static-libraries

So far I have been creating a static library each for OSX (Cocoa static library) and iOS(Cocoa Touch Static Library)

But when looking at the build setting for an iOS cocoa touch static library, I found that the Deployment section contains an entry "Mac OSX Deployment Target". Does that mean that a cocoa touch static library can be linked to by apps compiled for osx ?

Comment: why do you ask this question if you can check it by yourself?

Comment: Maybe they can be used, but shouldn't be? I'm trying to test it myself, but I don't know if this is the kind of thing that breaks only under specific circumstances.